# PHP curl: curl_setopt() fopencookie failed

Tags: php, curl, libcurl, fopen

I'm trying to write a script, which would cache images, but am stuck with the following error message:

```
Nov  4 12:55:19 centos httpd: PHP Fatal error:  curl_setopt() [<a href='function.curl-setopt'>function.curl-setopt</a>]: fopencookie failed in /var/www/html/proxy3.php on line 6
```

I have prepared a simpler script which still has this problem:

```
<?php
#phpinfo();
$fh = fopen('/tmp/yahoo.html', 'xb');
if ($fh) {
        $ch = curl_init('http://www.yahoo.com/');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh); # XXX the line 6
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        #curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/dev/null');
        #curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/dev/null');
        #curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookies.txt');
        #curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cookies.txt');
        curl_exec($ch);

        if(!curl_errno($ch)) {
                 $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
                  echo 'Took '.$info['total_time'] .
                    's to send a request to '.$info['url'];
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($fh);
} else {
        echo 'Can not open /tmp/yahoo.html';
}
?>
```

In the /tmp dir I then see a zero-sized file:

```
afarber@centos:html> ls -alZ /tmp/yahoo.html
-rw-r--r--  apache apache user_u:object_r:httpd_tmp_t      /tmp/yahoo.html
```

Does anybody please have an idea, what is going wrong here?

I've tried setting/not setting **CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR** and **CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE** - to /dev/null and/or to /tmp/cookies.txt. I've tried **sudo touch /tmp/cookies.txt; sudo chown apache.apache /tmp/cookies.txt** too. This just doesn't work.

Actually I don't need cookies in my script, I'd be happy to disable them in curl.

I'm using **fopen(... , "xb")** on purpose, so that only 1 script instance will write to the cached file in my real script.

I'm using CentOS 5.5 with php-5.1.6-27.el5 and unmodified php.ini

Thank you,
Alex

P.S. And here is my real image proxy script, which fails with the same fopencookie error message. I can't use **fopen(...., 'wb')** there, I *must* use **fopen(.... 'xb')**:

```
<?php

define('MIN_SIZE', 1024);
define('MAX_SIZE', 1024 * 1024);
define('CACHE_DIR', '/var/www/cached_avatars/');

$img = urldecode($_GET['img']);
# URL sanity checks omitted here for brevity
$cached = CACHE_DIR . md5($img);
$writefh = @fopen($cached, 'xb');
# the file is not cached yet, download it!
if ($writefh) {
        $ch = curl_init($img);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $writefh);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
        #curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $matches[1]);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        #curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/dev/null');
        #curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/dev/null');
        #curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, CACHE_DIR . 'cookies.txt');
        #curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, CACHE_DIR . 'cookies.txt');
        curl_exec($ch);

        $error    = curl_errno($ch);
        $length   = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD);
        $mime     = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
        $is_image = ($mime != NULL &&
                     (stripos($mime, 'image/gif') !== FALSE ||
                      stripos($mime, 'image/png') !== FALSE ||
                      stripos($mime, 'image/jpg') !== FALSE ||
                      stripos($mime, 'image/jpeg') !== FALSE));

        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($writefh);

        if ($error || $length < MIN_SIZE || $length > MAX_SIZE || !$is_image) {
                unlink($cached);
                exit('Download failed: ' . $img);
        }
} else {
        $finfo  = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
        $mime   = finfo_file($finfo, $cached);
        $length = filesize($cached);
        finfo_close($finfo);
}

$readfh = fopen($cached, 'rb');
if ($readfh) {
        header('Content-Type: ' . $mime);
        header('Content-Length: ' . $length);

        while (!feof($readfh)) {
                $buf = fread($readfh, 8192);
                echo $buf;
        }

        fclose($readfh);

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the responses, I've ended up with this PHP/cURL-script for caching images (needed by Flash apps to circumvent a missing crossdomain.xml) - seems to work ok with CentOS 5 Linux and php-5.1.6-27.el5:

```
<?php

define('MIN_SIZE', 512);
define('MAX_SIZE', 1024 * 1024);
define('CACHE_DIR', '/var/www/cached_avatars/');

$img = urldecode($_GET['img']);
# img sanity checks omitted here
$cached = CACHE_DIR . md5($img);

if (is_readable($cached)) {
        $finfo  = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
        $mime   = finfo_file($finfo, $cached);
        $length = filesize($cached);
        finfo_close($finfo);
} else {
        $writefh = fopen($cached, 'wb');
        if ($writefh) {
                flock($writefh, LOCK_EX);
                $ch = curl_init($img);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $writefh);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $matches[1]);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
                curl_exec($ch);

                $error    = curl_errno($ch);
                $length   = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD);
                $mime     = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
                $is_image = ($mime != NULL &&
                             (stripos($mime, 'image/gif') !== FALSE ||
                              stripos($mime, 'image/png') !== FALSE ||
                              stripos($mime, 'image/jpg') !== FALSE ||
                              stripos($mime, 'image/jpeg') !== FALSE));

                curl_close($ch);
                fclose($writefh);
                if ($error || $length < MIN_SIZE || $length > MAX_SIZE || !$is_image) {
                        unlink($cached);
                        exit('Download failed: ' . $img);
                }
        }
}

$readfh = fopen($cached, 'rb');
if ($readfh) {
        header('Content-Type: ' . $mime);
        header('Content-Length: ' . $length);

        flock($readfh, LOCK_SH);

        while (!feof($readfh)) {
                $buf = fread($readfh, 8192);
                echo $buf;
        }

        fclose($readfh);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because of the `x` mode. `fopen` when used with `x` mode returns `false` if the file already exists. In your case the file already exists, `$fh` will be `false` and when this is passed to `curl_setopt` you get this error.

To fix this try changing `xb` to `wb`.

Comment: No, at the 1st run the /tmp/yahoo.html doesn't exist. I've rewritten my code to make it more clear. It still fails with the (misleading?) fopencookie error message.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is only one script to access the file at the same time, you should use `cb` option + `flock`:

```
$fh = fopen('/tmp/yahoo.html', 'cb');
if (flock($fh, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB) {
    //ftruncate($fh, 0); -- truncate the file if that's what you want
    //continue as usual
}
else {
    //could not obtain lock (without waiting)
}
```

Comment: fopen(...., "xb") is better option for me, because I want to download the image just once (please see the real script at the bottom of my question). With "cb" it will be downloaded again and again. Also, I think flock() is not needed, when you use "cb". But anyway, thanks for your answer. I've also filed a PHP bug at http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53241

Comment: @Alex I've fixed the bug, it will be in PHP 5.3.4, which is due to December. I haven't tested, but I think 'cb' will have the same problem as 'xb', i.e. a file opened with 'cb' will also give a fopencookie error. I really can't see a work-around here except using a separate file with 'xb' as a lock and them if fopen is successful, open the real one with with 'wb'.

Comment: Thank you, I'll stick with using fopen(..., 'wb') and flock() so long.